# Binding a nested array to a list in a table

Tags: arrays, xml, list, nested, sapui5

I am trying to bind a nested array to a list in a table.

```
{
    "activities": [{
            "activityId": "1",
            "activityName": "tennis",
            "activityHours": [{
                "hour": "09:00",
                "instructor": "dave"
            }, {
                "hour": "10:00",
                "instructor": "Emma"
            }]
        }, {
            "activityId": "2",
            "activityName": "swimming",
            "activityHours": [{
                "hour": "09:00",
                "instructor": "Ella"
            }, {
                "hour": "10:00",
                "instructor": "Ron"
            }]
        }

    ]

}
```

my view.xml code:

```
<Table id="tblFactories" items="{path: 'data>/activities'}">
    <items>
<ColumnListItem >
<cells>
<Text text="{data>activityName}"></Text>
<List  items="{path: 'data>/activityHours'}" >
<StandardListItem  title="{data>hour}" ></StandardListItem>
</List>
    </cells>
</ColumnListItem>
</items>
</Table>
```

but it is not working.
does anyone know what is the correct syntax for the List binding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your XML code, the path is incorrect. For the List, activityHours is a property of the parent object so you should remove the '/'. For the List the context will be as below.

[image]

```
<Table id="tblFactories" items="{data>/activities}">
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Activity Name" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Hours" />
        </Column>
     </columns>   
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem >
            <cells>
                    <Text text="{data>activityName}"></Text>                        
                    <List  items="{data>activityHours}" >
                    <StandardListItem  title="{data>hour}" ></StandardListItem>
                    </List>                        
            </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>
```